# Pass Variable using $_GET to PHP Download Script

Tags: php, get

I have the following URL:

`http://www.solutionssoftwarematrix.com/download.php?filename=CreatingandMarketingthePerfectYouTubeVideo.zip`

I am trying to pass the string variable in to the PHP script (below) when someone clicks the link above.

Here is the script (download.php):

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Simple-and-Secure-PHP-Download-Script-with-Limits-Tutorial/1/

THE LINES BELOW with BOLD AREAS are where my `$_GET` FUNCTION is BEING ADDED, however, I keep receiving parse errors OR it does not pull the filename, and the download does not work.

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="http://www.yourdomain.com/ebookfordownloads/$_GET['$filename']"');

readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/$_GET['$filename']");


header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="http://www.yourdomain.com/ebookfordownloads/$_GET['$filename']"');
readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/$_GET['$filename']");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_VARIABLE using $\_GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345605/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable-using-get)

Comment: Take a look at the now highligted code, you can see that the `$_GET` variable ends the original strings opening `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is how it should be:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="http://www.yourdomain.com/ebookfordownloads/' . $_GET['filename'] . '"');


readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/" . $_GET['filename']);


header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="http://www.yourdomain.com/ebookfordownloads/' . $_GET['filename'] . '"');
readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/" . $_GET['filename'] );
```

Take a look at string concatenation in PHP.

Also: `$_GET['$filename']` means that you are asking PHP to get everything after `?$filename=` in url. But your url has no `$filename` parameter, only `filename`, so it should be modified to `$_GET['filename']`. Or, if you have a name of parameter stored in variable called `$filename` like this: `$filename = 'filename'`, it should be changed to `$_GET[$filename]`

Comment: THANkS A LOT!!!  That worked...  No, the user cannot set the filename parameter. It is embedded within the html link. And if they try to edit the url on their own, it won't work because the referring page and php script have session key validation.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- This syntax is invalid: `'$_GET['$filename` ... The apostrophe before `'$filename` closes the string.  What you probably want to do is `downloads/' . $_GET[$filename]` -- concatenation
- This syntax is also invalid: `"downloads/$_GET['$filename"` -- with array access in a quoted string, you cannot have an apostrophe.  Again, concatenation is your best bet: `"downloads/" . $_GET[$filename]`
- I'm not sure whether you want `$_GET['$filename']` or `$_GET[$filename]` or `$_GET['filename']`.  There is a very important difference between the three.
- Your code has a large vulnerability if a user can set `$filename` somehow (or the `filename` get parameter, if that is what you intend to use).

Comment: No, the user cannot set the filename parameter.  It is embedded within the html link.  And if they try to edit the url on their own, it won't work because the referring page and php script have session key validation.  Your concatenation suggestion eliminated the parse error BUT when the file tried to download, the name was blank...  Which tells me that the GET variable is not being added to the end of the url.  It works great without the GET function, but I need the name of the download file to change dynamically...

Comment: @user1818333 please look at bullet #3

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting basic [PHP string functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). To add variables like that, you'll have to use this:

```
readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/{$_GET['$filename']}");
```

or concat them:

```
readfile("/your/absolute/server/path/html/ebookfordownloads/".$_GET['$filename']);
```

Not to mention the Very Big Security Hole when using user input (`$_GET` variables) verbatim in your code. Do validation before you use the given information.

Comment: @ Bart, When I change the syntax to your suggestions, I receive the following error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in CODE

Comment: Could you update the complete code in your question? Ow, and did you read the link I provided?